# Autorelease and assigning to nil

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

How the memory management behave when we assign nil to an autoreleased object? Does it get deallocated instantly or does it deallocated with the autorelease pool ?

For etc,

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@","MY_STRING"]; //Autorelease object

myString = nil;//What will happen here ? Does it get deallocated ? Or Will it get deallocated with the autolrelease pool ?
```

Comment: Are you using ARC or MRC?

Comment: Great if you could give the explanation for both environments ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever any local variable is being assigned with `nil`, then that variable changes its pointing memory to 0x0000000. By this, the value presented at the address before will got unpointed.

And, the function of `Autoreleasepool` is to free the current running program or project or a particular environment's unreferenced addresses. So, the value which is previously being pointed is freed up by `Autoreleasepool`.